# How handler control stackframes are placed relative to each other in Koka?

Tags: delimited-continuations, koka

I have a following Koka snippet here and I would like for someone to explain what happens to stackframes when handlers are invoked. I've tried to make handlers stack frames also visible by printing values & global counters and I have desugared when expression.

```
effect foo<a> { control foo() : a }

fun main() {
  var c:int := 0
  val r = (handler {
      return(x:int) { println("in RET ctrl: " ++ x.show); x*2 }
      control foo() { 
        c := c + 1
        val this_c:int = c
        println("in FOO ctrl_1. c is: " ++ c.show)
        val r1 = resume(3)
        println("in FOO ctrl_2, r1: " ++ r1.show ++ " this_c is: " ++ this_c.show)
        r1*3
      }
  })(fn(){ 
    println("throw first foo")
    val first:int = foo()
    println("throw second foo, first: " ++ first.show)
    val snd:int = foo()
    println("got second: " ++ snd.show ++ " RET SUM: " ++ (first + snd).show)
    (first + snd)
  })
  println(r)
}
```

The result is following:

```
throw first foo
in FOO ctrl_1. c is: 1
throw second foo, first: 3
in FOO ctrl_1. c is: 2
got second: 3 RET SUM: 6
in RET ctrl: 6
in FOO ctrl_2, r1: 12 this_c is: 2
in FOO ctrl_2, r1: 36 this_c is: 1
108
```

How TWO "FOO_CTRL" handler frames are now underneath the original FN() invocation as well as RET handler?

Comment: Can someone create tag "koka-lang"?

Comment: I created a new tag for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the terminology usually used for Koka, but here's an answer based on my general knowledge of delimited continuations:

The first time `foo()` is invoked, it has access to the continuation (call it `k1`):

```
val first:int = HOLE
println("throw second foo, first: " ++ first.show)
val snd:int = foo()
println("got second: " ++ snd.show ++ " RET SUM: " ++ (first + snd).show)
(first + snd)
```

Note that if `foo()` did not invoke this continuation, it would just go away. In terms of stack frames, that frame is no longer on the call stack; it's been reified as a function. The call stack looks like this:

```
foo (resume=k1)
<handle frame>
main
```

But the first `foo()` does in fact invoke this continuation: `resume(3)`. Now the stack looks like this:

```
k1
foo (resume=k1)
<handle frame>
main
```

`k1` eventually calls `foo` again. Its argument continuation (call it `k2`) starts with `val snd:int = HOLE`. But the first `foo` has established the prompt again, so that the call stack becomes:

```
foo (resume=k2)
foo (resume=k1)
<handle frame>
main
```

Then the second `foo` invokes `resume` (=`k2`).

When the first `foo` invoked `resume`, it first inserted a new prompt for the effect, so that when the effect is invoked the part of the call stack which is captured and removed ends above the existing `foo` frame, not the `<handle frame>`. A handler for a different effect established before the `foo` handler would not have matched the established prompt, so would have captured and removed every instance of `foo` on the stack.

Unfortunately, try as I might I have not yet found a definitive source stating that, of the variety of possible control operations possible for use with multi-prompt delimited continuations, Koka's `resume` is the one which establishes a new prompt before invoking the captured delimited continuation. I can only infer it from the behavior you have pointed out.